# Mysql, Cannot Create Table

Tags: mysql, unix, primary-key, create-table

Everything seems to be correct in this code and I cannot wrap my head around what I am missing here. I have:

```
 Create Table Instruments( Inst-ID INT PRIMARY KEY, 
                           Type varchar(15), 
                           MakerName varchar(25), 
                           Year varchar(4) );
```

Where is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You must create the database before creating the table. And next you must select the database on which you want to create the database table.

Steps for creating database in MySql are:

(Considering your example it should be like this.)

- Step 1: Create database Instruments; This query will create a database in mysql with a name "Instruments".
- Step 2: use Instruments;
  This query will select the database on which you want to create table.
- Step 3: create table using following query below:

  ```
  create Table Instruments( Inst-ID INT not null PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
                            Type varchar(15), 
                            MakerName varchar(25), 
                            Year varchar(4) );
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Instruments` (
  `Inst-ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Type` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `MakerName` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Year` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Inst-ID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

you forgot `` and you forgot the Engine , Default Charset and the auto_increment